# React. Api request inside of a useEffect hook (Calling an async function)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios, page-lifecycle

I'm building a project in React and I got a component that holds several components. This component needs to fetch data when mounted and later when changes occur on the child components. At first, I tried using the useEffect hook with a "shouldRefetch" dependency like so:

```
[shouldRefetch, setShouldRefetch] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [shouldRefetch])

const fetchData = async () => {
    // fetchingdata.. 
    setData(response.data); //useState hook
    setShouldRefetch(false);
}

const onFetch = () = {
    setShouldRefetch(true);
}

//child component

return (
 <Child onFetch={onFetch} />
)
```

After this code sent too many requests to my API, I tried passing the child component the fetchData function and removed the dependency from the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [])

// ...

return (
 <Child fetchData={fetchData} />
)
```

This solved most duplicate api calls but when the page loads I'm still getting two api calls being sent out in the network tab (chrome dev tools). I know it's becuase of the useEffect but I don't undertand why. Can anyone help me undertand this issue?

Thanks in advance

I tried fetching data on page load and expecting it to occur only once and later only when I call my async function to fetch data. I just don't understand why I'm seeing a request being fired twice in the network tab.

Comment: Does this happen in production too? Because in development, if you're using StrictMode, each useEffect will fire twice.

Comment: @DallogFheir I'm currently working on the project and it is using StrictMode. Why would it cause the useEffect to fire twice?

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have enabled '**React.StrictMode**'. In this case every **useEffect**() on your component will run twice on mount by default. You may find this configuration on your **index.tsx** file (for typescript). You can fix this by removing the StrictMode wrapper but that won't be the best solution.
Because you can do a trick to prevent api call from running twice,

```
  let isFetching = false;

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("/dummy.json").then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching) return;
    fetchData();
    isFetching = true;
  }, []);
```

Here, we have declared a variable outside of useEffect() with default value false. After executing the fetch function we have set ***isFetching = true***.
As we are checking **isFetching** in the first line of **useEffect**() this will prevent the ***fetchData***() function to run 2nd time and your fetch api call will only run once on component mount.

Comment: I'll try it. I am using StrictMode. Why would it be enabled by default and why would my useEffect fire off twice?

Comment: Strict mode forces you to follow basic react guideline and prevents you from doing any mistake. It thinks running useEffect() twice would give you the same result and you might handle it. It's a comnon behavior from react

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue for me. I might try a different later. Maybe useEffect isn't the best solution for what I'm trying to do

Comment: Yes, there are libraries to make this kind of api call on component mount. For example, react-query. It provides a lot more control on triggering an api cal.

Comment: is that the right way to deal with it? is it good enough for the production?

Comment: For production, its better to use react-query or rtk-query libraries for data fetching. These provide lot more functionality like client side caching. You may check those libraries